# Storage class specified for 'gdt_flush'

Tags: c++, assembly, osdev

I am writing a operating system that needs to interface with some external assembler functions. I put the declaration in the header:

```
namespace Kernel
{
    class DescriptorTables
    {
        public:
        void init();
        void gdt_set_gate(s32int,u32int,u32int,u8int,u8int);
        private:
        extern void gdt_flush(u32int);
        struct gdt_entry_struct
        {
        //...
```

When the code is ran, it produces

> DescriptorTables.h:10:31: error: storage class specified for 'gdt_flush'

I have never seen this error before, Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want `gdt_flush()` to achieve, but my best guess is you want to make it possible to re-implement its functionality; for that, you'd want `virtual`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    extern void gdt_flush(u32int);
```

You can't say `extern` like that within a class. `extern` is a storage class, which explains the message you're seeing.